# What happen if I try to charge Macbook Pro 2016 from 4 port at a time?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

New Macbook Pro 2016 allow user to power from any of 4 ports.
I'm wondering what will happen when I try to charge from every port at a time.

1. Will it explode?
2. Will it charge from first plugged cable?
3. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will charge from the port that supplies the most power. See "charging" section:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207256